If all max area planar sections of a solid are centrally symmetric, will the solid as whole be centrally symmetric?
It is known that every planar section of an ellipsoid is an ellipse - a centrally symmetric planar figure.

Are there convex solids other than ellipsoids with the property that all its planar sections are centrally symmetric planar figures?

If a convex solid has the property: all its maximal area planar sections - sections of max area with normal in any specified direction - are centrally symmetric planar figures, does it imply that the solid is centrally symmetric?


Note 1: a variant of 2 can be asked with 'perimeter' replacing 'area'.
Adding a question on shadows (orthogonal projections of a solid onto a plane) in the same spirit:

Which convex solids have the property: all its shadows  have central symmetry?

Note 2: one can also ask about convex solids with both all shadows and all max planar sections having central symmetry. Some further thoughts on this thread are recorded at https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2024/06/an-addition-to-mathoverflow-post.html.

What if we only know that all the sections through a fixed point are centrally symmetric - is there a non-degenerate counterexample then? (If we take only the sections through a fixed internal segment, a triangular prism aligned with that segment is an easy counterexample: all the sections are rectangles.) By non-degenerate I mean: other than a flat 2-dimensional convex "solid" with the fixed point outside the plane containing it.

I don’t know. It does look v plausible that “ if there is an interior point such that all sections of the solid containing that point r centrally symmetric, the solid is centrally symmetric”. But it is a variant I couldn’t think of! Thanks.
